# Jquery Mobile css overrides my body css

Tags: jquery, css

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css overrides my body styling

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; background-image:url(img/bggradient.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x">
```

Apparently I uses the color F6F6F6 which occurs 12 times in that css file, which I find pretty difficult to read. How could I re-override the body styling here?

Comment: You could always try adding the `!important` declaration, like `background-image:url(img/bggradient.jpg) !important;`. An easier solution might be to link the jQuery mobile CSS file first, and then your CSS file later in the HTML file. As long as your CSS is structured properly, it will override the earlier declarations in jQM.

Comment: Did both and I still have that #F6F6F6 background.

Comment: @Set Sail Media You can check here: http://jenseickhoff.de/slider/rechner-for-touch.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
.ui-page{background:transparent !important;} 
.ui-body-c{background:transparent !important;} 
.ui-page-active{background:transparent !important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this css in your style sheet.

```
ui-page ui-body-c.ui-page-active{
   background:transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Obviously something else is going on then. Can you provide a live link to the issue for debugging?

Comment: can you provide a live link

Comment: It's not the body that's the issue, it's a div over the top with a background color. Try .ui-page { background: transparent; }

Comment: Why is there a div over the top?

Answer (score 1):

You could try by adding !important declaration like `background-image:url(img/bggradient.jpg) !important;`

Even if you are not accessing Try this:

```
html, body{
background-image:url(img/bggradient.jpg) !important;
}
```

Comment: Still I have an #F6F6F6 Background and not my image.

Comment: @ C-Link: You can check it out live here: http://jenseickhoff.de/slider/rechner-for-touch.html

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles will always override styles in a CSS stylesheet (because you can't be more specific than inline styles on an element) UNLESS you use !important tags in the stylesheet.

For example:

```
body { background: #FFF !important; }
```

This will override any background inline style javascript adds.

Comment: Does not yield any different result in this case unfortunately.

Comment: Need a live link to see what's going on then. Important tags will override any other styles on that element (unless they also use important tags).